# Express Gateway - JWT Verification policy checkCredentialExistence for remote auth server

Tags: jwt, express-gateway

I am using express gateway as API Gateway middleware with the following setup.

1. Express gateway serves as gateway only.
2. My auth (user database) server is at a different location and I am routing all login request to the auth server to get jwt.
3. Multiple resource server is behind express gateway. Which will not authorize or authenticate any request. *All incoming request is treated as already authenticated*

I have setup the EG config such a way that it verifies the JWT and only passes requests with correct JWT. Because the authorization `checkCredentialExistence` on the gateway itself.

### Problem

When users sends logout request I revoke both access & refresh token from the auth server. BUT, the *revoked* JWT token still a valid token. And gateway keep passing the incoming requests with revoked jwt.

Is there a way to check with remote api if JWT is still valid in Express gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jwt access token is kind of self signed token and there is no way to revoke it, you can use refrence token for this senario